# XML file output from XmlWriter

Tags: c#, xmlwriter

XmlWriter in Visual Studio 2012,

How can I output the following:

```xml
<Amt>
    <InstdAmt Ccy=”EUR”>340.00</InstdAmt>
</Amt>
```

The following does not work:

```cs
const string cur = "Ccy=" + @"""EUR";
writer.WriteStartElement("Amt");
writer.WriteElementString("InstdAmt", cur, "340.00");              
writer.WriteEndElement();
```

Comment: Which is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

When you want to write node attributes, you can use [`WriteAttributeString(string localName, string value)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y13bc3d8.aspx).

This should produce the desired output

```
writer.WriteStartElement("Amt");

  writer.WriteStartElement("InstdAmt");
  writer.WriteAttributeString("Ccy", "EUR");
  writer.WriteString("340.00");
  writer.WriteEndElement();

writer.WriteEndElement();
```

See the [XmlTextWriter reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.aspx) for more options.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `Close()` method of the `XmlWriter` object in order to write to the file:

```
writer.Close()
```